# Traverse JSON logic into a statement

Tags: json, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, logical-operators

JSON input as:

```
{
  "AND": 
     [ 
       {"OR": [ { "EQUALS" : {"X":"Y"} }, { "EQUALS": {"Z":"W"} } ]},
       {"EQUALS" : {"A": "B"} } 
     ]
}
```

EQUALS takes a pair 
AND - OR take a list

```
               AND
             /    \
            OR     EQ
            / \    / \
           EQ  EQ  A B
           / \ / \
          X  Y Z  W
```

Output after traversing should be:

```
( A EQUALS B AND ( X EQUALS Y OR Z EQUALS W ) )
```

Theoretically I understand that I should have the JSON as a tree and traverse it in an In-Order (left-root-right) method.

Practically, I implemented the in-order method that accepts a tree (tagged with root and left and right.. as deep as it can get). However, I can't seem to have the right idea of how to read the JSON as a tree and tag its content, if that's the right idea!

Any ideas?

Comment: In which programming language are you working?

Comment: I'm using Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can use an in-order traversal. Using recursion, it could look like this:

```py
def dfs(node):
    key, value = list(node.items())[0]
    if isinstance(value, list):
        yield "("
        yield from dfs(value[0])
        yield ")"
        yield key
        yield "("
        yield from dfs(value[1])
        yield ")"
    else:
        a, b = list(value.items())[0]
        if isinstance(b, (list, dict)):
            yield key
            yield "("
            yield from dfs(value)
            yield ")"
        else:
            yield a
            yield key
            yield b
```

Example use:

```
tree = {
    "NOT": {
        "AND": [{
            "OR": [{
                "NOT": {
                    "EQUALS" : {"X":"Y"}
                } 
            }, {
                "EQUALS": {"Z":"W"}
            }]
        }, {
            "EQUALS" : {"A": "B"}
        }]
    }
}

print(" ".join(dfs(tree)))
```

Output for this example:

```
NOT ( ( ( NOT ( X EQUALS Y ) ) OR ( Z EQUALS W ) ) AND ( A EQUALS B ) )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this looks neat. However, if I make an addition of the logical operator NOT, which would have only one child of an array or a pair, it'd break. Is it wrong to continue with dfs when one of the roots have only one child? or can we adjust it?
{ "NOT" : {
    "AND": 
        [ 
           {"OR": [ { "EQUALS" : {"X":"Y"} }, { "EQUALS": {"Z":"W"} } ]},
           {"EQUALS" : {"A": "B"} } 
        ] 
   }
}

Comment: Extended my answer with support for unary operators.